# How to improve the pattern matching on a list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have a big list, which may carry thousands to millions of entries. I set a window of finite size to slide over the list. I need to count the matched elements in the windows and repeat the procedure by sliding the window 1 position forward at a time. Here is a simple example of a list

```
L = [1 2 1 3 4 5 1 2 1 2 2 2 3 ]
```

Assuming the window is of the length of 3, it will capture

1. [1 2 1] which contains one pair of matching elements (1 & 1)
2. move the windows forward by 1 position => [2 1 3], no matching elements
3. move the windows forward by 1 position => [1 3 4], no matching elements
4. move the windows forward by 1 position => [3 4 5], no matching elements
5. move the windows forward by 1 position => [4 5 1], no matching elements
6. move the windows forward by 1 position => [5 1 2], no matching elements
7. move the windows forward by 1 position => [1 2 1], 1 matching elements (1 & 1)
8. move the windows forward by 1 position => [2 1 2], 1 matching elements (2 & 2)
9. move the windows forward by 1 position => [1 2 2], 1 matching elements (2 & 2)
10. move the windows forward by 1 position => [2 2 2], 3 matching elements ([2 2 -], [2 - 2], [- 2 2])
11. move the windows forward by 1 position => [2 2 3], 1 matching elements (2 & 2)

So total 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 3 + 1 = 8 matching pairs. I found the idea to use itertools to find the combination of all elements in a window and develop a code to find all the matching pairs

```
import itertools
L = [1,2,1,3,4,5,1,2,1,2,2,2,3]
winlen = 3
totalMatch = 0
for n in range(len(L)-winlen+1):
    window = [L[n+i] for i in range(winlen)]
    A = list(itertools.combinations(window, 2))
    match = [a==b for a, b in A]
    totalMatch += sum(match)
```

it works for a short list but for the list and the windows getting large, this code is so slow. I have been working with C++ for years and decide to switch to python, I will appreciate it if there is any hint to improve the efficiency of the code.

Comment: It is used for data analysis to find out the matching pattern over a large set of data. Each data point is a record of some status of the system over time. The purpose is to find the matched status within a certain time (windows).

Comment: You are only ever matching numbers, right?

Comment: Yes, they are all numbers (positive integers)

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa ah ... that gives me some direction, I am not familiar with how it could be done, but will do some research to smell the idea first ;)

Comment: Why is the answer 3 matches for step #10 with [2, 2, 2], and not 2 matches? What would it be for [2, 2, 2, 5] or [2, 2, 2, 2] ?

Comment: Suggest change window creation to a slice you pass directly to combinations: L[n:n+winlen]

Comment: @learning2learn -- see the note under that entry: `([2 2 -], [2 - 2], [- 2 2])`. They are counting possible pairs.

Comment: Please fix `L = [1 2 1 3 4 5 1 2 1 2 2 2 3 ]`, that's not valid Python.

Comment: @learning2learn, it is asking to match any possible pair within the window, hence, for [2,2,2], it could be [2, 2, *], [2, *, 2] and [*, 2, 2], a total of 3 possibilities.  If it is for [2,2,2,5], it is still 3 matching pairs [2,2,*,*], [2,*,2,*], [*,2,2,5]; for [2,2,2,2] it could be [2,2,*,*], [2,*,2,*], [2, *, *, 2], [*,2,2,*], [*, 2,*,2],[*,*,2,2], a total of 6 matching pairs

Comment: So how would you code this efficiently in C++ and would that be `Ο(1)` time with a growing window and list size?

Comment: I like this problem as is roughly similar to cases where I've had to mine data from application logs, but on a much smaller scale than the challenge here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep track of the data in your window more efficiently? This is O(|L|) instead of your O(|L|*winlen^2). It keeps the window's element counts in `ctr` and the window's matches in `match`. For example, when a new value enters the window and there are already two instances of that value in the window, you get two new matches. Similarly for a value falling out of the window, it takes as many matches with it as there are other instances of it in the window.

```
from collections import Counter

L = [1,2,1,3,4,5,1,2,1,2,2,2,3]
winlen = 3

totalMatch = match = 0
ctr = Counter()
for i, x in enumerate(L):
    
    # Remove old element falling out of window
    if i >= winlen:
        ctr[L[i-winlen]] -= 1
        match -= ctr[L[i-winlen]]

    # Add new element to window
    match += ctr[x]
    ctr[x] += 1

    # Update the total (for complete windows)
    if i >= winlen - 1:
        totalMatch += match

print(totalMatch)
```

Benchmark results with `L` and `winlen` multiplied by 20:

```
 38.75 ms  original
  0.18 ms  Manuel

 38.73 ms  original
  0.19 ms  Manuel

 38.87 ms  original
  0.18 ms  Manuel
```

Benchmark code (also includes testing code for all lists of numbers 1 to 3 of lengths 0 to 9):

```
from timeit import repeat
import itertools
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter

def original(L, winlen):
    totalMatch = 0
    for n in range(len(L)-winlen+1):
        window = [L[n+i] for i in range(winlen)]
        A = list(itertools.combinations(window, 2))
        match = [a==b for a, b in A]
        totalMatch += sum(match)
    return totalMatch

def Manuel(L, winlen):
    totalMatch = match = 0
    ctr = Counter()
    for i, x in enumerate(L):
        if i >= winlen:
            ctr[L[i-winlen]] -= 1
            match -= ctr[L[i-winlen]]
        match += ctr[x]
        ctr[x] += 1
        if i >= winlen - 1:
            totalMatch += match
    return totalMatch

def test():
    for n in range(10):
        print('testing', n)
        for T in product([1, 2, 3], repeat=n):
            L = list(T)
            winlen = 3
            expect = original(L, winlen)
            result = Manuel(L, winlen)
            assert result == expect, (L, expect, result)

def bench():
    L = [1,2,1,3,4,5,1,2,1,2,2,2,3] * 20
    winlen = 3 * 20
    for _ in range(3):
        for func in original, Manuel:
            t = min(repeat(lambda: func(L, winlen), number=1))
            print('%6.2f ms ' % (t * 1e3), func.__name__)
        print()

test()
bench()
```

Comment: This isn't much faster, if at all.

Comment: @jbflow What makes you think so? It rather obviously is.

Comment: my mistake I left the print in there while timing it. It's coming in about twice as fast

Comment: @jbflow It's much more than twice as fast. You must not be timing it *"for the list and the windows getting large"*.

Comment: Thanks @Manuel. It is a good one, let me try to apply them to the large dataset for testing.

Comment: I just timed both code snipets using timeit. It likely is in that case based on the O notation.

Comment: @jbflow Multiply `L` and `winlen` by let's say 10 (which is still small).

Comment: I am getting an answer of `4` with `L = [1,1,1]` and window size of three. I don't think that's correct unless I misunderstood the question. Maybe just and edge case?

Comment: @Manuel Yeah I can see the improvements as you start to scale the winlen now. Originally thought it was the list that was getting big.

Comment: @MarkM Should be fixed now, added testing code. Thanks.

Comment: Nice solution, much faster than `np.bincount`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.bincount` in a for loop, determine the number of combinations for each number/bin, and sum it up with the total.

```
import numpy as np

L = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
winlen = 3

L = np.array(L) # convert to array to speed up indexing

total = 0
for i in range(len(L) - winlen + 1):
    bc = np.bincount(L[i:i+winlen]) # bincount on the window
    bc = bc[bc>1] # get rid of all single and empty values
    bc = bc * (bc-1) // 2 # gauss addition, number of combinations of each number
    total += np.sum(bc) # sum up combinations, and add to total

print(total)
# 8
```

Comment: It is interesting. I am reading all those commands used to understand how it works

Comment: Be aware that this is about a factor of 10 slower than @Manuel's solution for large input sequences.

Comment: Do we have the same complexity? (I don't know numpy much (a link to `bincount`'s documentation would help :-))

Comment: `bincount` is essentially like `Counter`, but without the dictionary overhead. It counts the number of occurences of integers in a sequence, so it needs to iterate it and keep count. This should be O(n * m), with n being sequence length and m being window length. It's consistently much slower than your solution, but faster then the original.

Comment: Ah, I see `L[i:i+winlen]` already makes its complexity worse. So it's unclear what you mean with "factor of 10 slower", as that only makes sense when the complexity class is the same.

Comment: The indexing is no complexity, but the nested loop is, yes.

Comment: How is it "no complexity"? Copying a list slice of length winlen takes O(winlen) time.

Comment: So, this should be O(n * m**2)? meh. I think you're right. Oh, I just replaced the list with an numpy array, which turns the list slice into a numpy slice/view, which eliminates on of the m's in the complexity.

Comment: Ok yes, with a numpy array the view part is fast. If I understand bincount correctly, its time depends not just on the window size but also the window elements? So rather O(|L| * winlen * maxval), I think.

Comment: @Manuel You are again correct, since `bc` has `maxval` number of elements, both the gauss sum and the summing `bc` scale with `maxval`. We can speed this up a little by throwing away values which only give a zero, I will edit.

Comment: The overhead of `bincount` is pretty bad compared to `Counter` if the data is sparse or has huge gaps. So my earlier statement was also wrong. With sparse data the dictionary wins by huge margins.

Comment: so enjoy reading all those discussion, I learn a lot from that